# Creating MySql Database on new install of c# application if it doesnt exist

Tags: c#, mysql, deployment

I am about to deploy my application and have came into a bit of trouble.

I have the connection string for the database held in the application.settings and need a way to check if the database exists when the program first starts up, and if it doesn't, i need the program to create it before starting the program.

I am assuming it would be a mysql statement to check if db exists, if not create. However, I don't know where or how to do this, can I create a mysql dump of a blank database with tables etc already created and use that?

I have already stored the mysql dll files locally so there is no problem with that, its just creating the database that the string wants to connect to before the application runs so there are no connection errors straight away.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = "my_db"
```

If it doesn't exist from the result set you get returned you can then create it.

This does pose questions regarding MySQL permissions and if your application should have user rights that enable such checking.

**Edit in response of comments.**

It isn’t clear if you create the connection string or not – I’ll assume the worst and that it is a part of the setup so your client can enter it (if you do know it the process below simplifies.

I would pass the connection string to the constructor of the `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` class, this then makes it easy to connect to the database using the `MySqlConnection` class.  I would use the properties from the new instance of the `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` class (Server, Host, User etc) to setup the `MySqlConnection` class.

If the connection didn’t work I would return information to the user and they can update their connection string.

Once I’ve successfully connected to the database I would then use the database name from the `Database` property of my `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` instance to build the query above.

If the command returns NULL the database doesn't exist and then needs creating, if the database does exist then the command will return the name of the database.

Now there are two paths:

1. **It Doesn't exist** – It needs creating, I would probably have an external SQL file with the create statements in (can be produced by MySQL dump by using the –nodata option).  I would parse this file and execute the create statements
2. **It does exist** – I would now check the structure of the database to make sure it is compatible before continuing the installation.

Comment: how would I implement this into c# code? I have tried using my current connection string and used executeScalar to get the return, but i get object reference errors. Thanks.

Comment: @Shaun we aren't here to write your code for you. How about showing what you've already tried.  I have answered your question, you execute that query and if it returns the database name it exists, if NULL is returned then it doesn't exist and you have to create it.  If you're getting an object reference error you're probably trying to do something with the NULL value that you shouldn't before checking if it is actually NULL

Comment: not asking you to write my code, I explained how I tried to implement it and stated that I was getting errors using it, I was just looking for a simple example of how that statement would be implemented using a connection string that has the name of the database I am trying to find, wasn't to sure if this would need to be removed from the string.

Nevermind, will keep trying.

Comment: @Shaun I've edited my answer - I really don't know how much clearer I can make it